# Update a dict with duplicate keys and keeping the index of each key the same in Python

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I am trying to update the json payload with a dict type info and keeping the key position the same as before as it is required by the task I am working on.

**Note** I understand that the implementation of type **dict** not allow duplicate keys, but I do need this done, so any work-around or hacky approach would helps.

I have a payload which I loaded from a json file

payload.json

```
{
    "name": "",
    "address": "",
    "age": " ",
    "ethnicities": "",
    "select": "",
    "sub-ethnicities": "",
    "select": "",
    "option1": "",
    "option2": ""
}
```

loading it

```
payload = json.load(open("payload.json"))
```

The I have the info:

```
info = {
    "name": "Spock",
    "ethnicities": "Vulcan",
    "select": "paternal",
    "sub-ethnicities": "human",
    "select": "maternal",
}
```

I am trying to insert above info into the payload and keeping the key indexes the way they were.

Expected result would be

```
{
    "name": "Spock",
    "address": "",
    "age": "",
    "ethnicities": "Vulcan",
    "select": "paternal",
    "sub-ethnicities": "human",
    "select": "maternal",
    "option1": "",
    "option2": ""
}
```

Using **data | info** or **data.update(info)** will removes the duplicate keys, which defeating the goal I am trying to archieve.

For example expected result is:

```
{
    "name": "Spock",
    "address": "",
    "age": "",
    "ethnicities": "Vulcan",
    "select": "paternal",
    "sub-ethnicities": "human",
    "select": "maternal",
    "Extra-ethnicities": "Asian",
    "select": "Asian"
}
```

but I got was the duplicate keys got removed.

```
    "name": "Spock",
    "address": "",
    "age": "",
    "ethnicities": "Vulcan",
    "select": "paternal",
    "sub-ethnicities": "human",
    "Extra-ethnicities": "Asian",
}
```

Comment: You can't have multiple of the same keys (like you have for select) in a python dictionary object. Most implementations of JSON parsers have the behavior of only using the last key when decoding, and this representation is certainly not going to work with a standard python dict object.

Comment: Your payload and info contain duplicate keys (`"select"`), which is not allowed in either json or Python. Other than that, either `payload | info` or `payload.update(info)`

Comment: @Grismar It's not technically invalid for json.. just uncommon. "An object whose names are all unique is interoperable in the sense that all software implementations receiving that object will agree on the name-value mappings.  When the names within an object are not unique, the behavior of software that receives such an object is unpredictable.  Many implementations report the last name/value pair only.  Other implementations report an error or fail to parse the object, and some implementations report all of the name/value pairs, including duplicates." https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159

Comment: The spec says "SHOULD be unique", so you're right in that they're technically allowed, although behaviour of duplicate keys is not well-defined and many editors and even some parsers don't allow it. For Python it's similar - it won't cause an error, but instead updates the first occurance with the last value. Again, you may run into Python-implementations that deal with it differently.

Comment: @Grismar I do understand the problem with implementation in the future, but for the purpose of this task, I need a work-around for this, a hacky way would solve it. I have some idea in mind, but cannot come up with an efficient aproach...

Comment: @Grismar I agree with you. I think you edited your comment which was originally saying that it was invalid json. I just wanted to add context for that, but yeah, avoid if possible 100%. The main benefit of JSON as I see it is to have language agnostic representation of data which is easily serialized/deserialized. Using non-standard representation of JSON defeats that purpose completely.

Comment: @JrBusiness both solutions I suggested in my comment will work, give them a try - or explain in the question why those don't work for you.

Comment: @flakes, you are technically correct, the best kind of correct

Comment: @Grismar I have updated on the thread

Comment: @JrBusiness although you're allowed to *define* a dict with duplicate keys, Python has no way of actually *maintaining* duplicate keys in a dict. What you're asking for cannot be done using Python dictionaries without at least strongly modifying how you define them (for example by using tuples that pair each text key with a unique index), and you'd probably need to eschew the use of the `json` module as well, and instead load the json yourself, to deal with the duplicate key there. I wouldn't recommend that though...

Comment: @flakes - I didn't think you didn't agree, I just wanted to confirm what you said and add a remark that the same is true for Python dicts. Technically possible, not clearly defined, absolutely not recommended - and as it turns out, not suitable for OP's problem, as they require these duplicate keys to persist.

Answer (score 0):

An operator for this was added in Python 3.9 as the [Union operator](https://peps.python.org/pep-0584/):

```py
payload_with_info = payload | info
print(payload_with_info)
>>>
{
    'address': '',
    'age': ' ',
    'ethnicities': 'Vulcan',
    'name': 'Spock',
    'option1': '',
    'option2': '',
    'select': 'maternal',
    'sub-ethnicities': 'human'
}
```